# Symfony can't find assets prefixed with web/ on local

Tags: image, .htaccess, symfony, mamp

I'm running the most recent version of Symfony through Mamp. I have some image assets prefixed with /web/ in my code base. Symfony can't seem pull them up when I go to my local url (u.local).

An example image asset url would be (relative path): /web/productEditor/image.png

In mamp under additional parameters for `<directory>` I have:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
```

I can't change the local code to just remove the /web/ part of the img src tag. Is there a way to configure .htaccess to ignore the "/web/" part of the url?

Can I configure Symfony to differently through mamp?

Directory Structure:

```
 Web Root
  -Web Folder
   --App.php (what boots up symfony)
   --productEditor
    ---Assets
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You question doesn't tell me where your app expect the images to be.  if its looking for them in  `/productEditor/image.png` in stead of `/web/productEditor/image.png` then the following may solve your issue. ( but i have not tested this )

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web/
RewriteRule ^web/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

With the full .htaccess block you have listed above it would be.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web/
    RewriteRule ^web/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

-Nathan

Comment: Sorry, I expect the images to be in the "/web/" folder, however the the web folder can't not be found if an img src requests it.

Comment: np, just a little hard to visualize.  can you list out your directory structure so we can see where `web` is related to the app root.

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: updated the rewrite condition / rule in my answer.  that rule may need to be tweaked depending on your local environment.  if it don't work let me know.